# busybox - Can't detect grub binaries

Tags: grub2, busybox, ash

I compiled GRUB from source, using pretty much default settings in a chroot debian sid environment using default `--prefix` so it installed in /usr/local.

When I copied the files over to a system with busybox as main core (Not even `bash` is installed), `ash` can't detect many grub binaries.

Due to that, I can't use `grub-install` or others (although I can run `grub-mkconfig`, but it says that it doesn't find `grub-probe`)

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /path/to/grub-install’ on the busybox system? Could be a different libc than on Debian.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It says 'not a dynamic executable'. I checked the others and the same thing happens.

Comment: Ok, then there could be an architecture mismatch. On the busybox system, what is the output of `uname  -a` and `file /path/to/grub-install` ?

Comment: On the busybox system, it shows the host information: 'Linux knotbuk 4.20.7-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 6 18:42:40 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux'. And the file command says: 'grub-install: ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=f1431424ec013366afa3113cabdf9324a982bf39, not stripped'

Comment: Do you have a `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` on the busybox system? If not, it may be possible to copy it over from the Debian system. But there may be other missing 80386 libraries. Try `ldd` again after the ld-linux.so.2 file is in place.

Comment: I checked, and it didn't (I didn't though of glibc apparently), so I copied it over. Now 'grub-install' does run, but now it says 'Too many levels of symbolic links'.

Comment: That probably means that, somewhere, you have a symlink that points to itself.

Comment: After you get everything working, please answer the question yourself, in the text box at the bottom of this page, including the steps you took. It will help others trying to do what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer was that I forgot to install glibc to the busybox system.

I copied `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` from a working system into the busybox environment. But it's preferable to install the whole set of glibc so all programs can run correctly.